# Can slice pull out effect be disabled while using AmCharts pie chart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Can slice pull out effect be disabled while using AmCharts pie chart?

The slice pull out effect seems to be there by default.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. To disable pull out animation, simply set [`pullOutDuration`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#pullOutDuration) to zero.

Or, if you want to disable pull out altogether, set [`pullOutRadius`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#pullOutRadius) to zero.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "pullOutDuration": 0,
  "pullOutRadius": 0,
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  }, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
  }, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
  }, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 99
  }, {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 60
  }, {
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "litres": 50
  }],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country"
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: However I do not need the pull out itself to happen, So that when i click a segment nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize you wanted to disable the pull out altogether (not just the animation effect). Updated my answer accordingly.